# need to get each checked checkboxes value which is in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function countChecked() {
    var n = $("input:checked").length;
    $("div").text(n + (n <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
  }
  countChecked();
  $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
});
```

```css
div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" checked="checked" value="Hourly" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Daily" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Weekly" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" checked="checked" value="Monthly" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Yearly" />
</form>
```

I need to get the value of all the checked checkboxes like "Hourly", "Daily"

how can I get all the value of the checked checkboxes
can anybody help me, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slight improvement on Pim Jager (guessing you want an array of the values returned):

```
function getCheckedNames(){
 var arr = new Array();
 var $checked = $('[@name=newsletter]:checked');
 $checked.each(function(){ 
  arr.push($(this).val());
 });
 return arr;
}
```

and with the improvement from duckyflip:

```
function getCheckedNames(){
  return jQuery('[@name=newsletter]:checked').map(function(){
   return this.value;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = $.makeArray($(":checkbox:checked").map(function(){
   return this.value 
})).join(', ')

alert(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to see what you're trying to do here, but I'm guessing this is what you're after:

```
$("input:checked").each(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: ya , ive already tried that but it doesn't get all of the checked checkboxes value , i need to get all of the checked checkboxes values

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
function updateChecked(){
 var arr = new Array();
 $('input:checkbox:checked').each( function() {
   arr.push($(this).val());
 });
 var checkboxesText = arr.join(', ');
 var moreText = (arr.length <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + ' checked!';
 $('div').text(checkboxesText + moreText);
}
```

This would set the div text to something like: "Hourly, Daily are checked!"